# Spark find max of date partitioned column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a parquet partitioned in the following way:

```
data
/batch_date=2020-01-20
/batch_date=2020-01-21
/batch_date=2020-01-22
/batch_date=2020-01-23
/batch_date=2020-01-24
```

Here batch_date which is the partition column is of date type.

I want only read the data from the latest date partition but as a consumer I don't know what is the latest value.

I could use a simple group by something like

```
df.groupby().agg(max(col('batch_date'))).first()
```

While this would work it's a very inefficient way since it involves a groupby.

I want to know if we can query the latest partition in a more efficient way.

Thanks.

Comment: maybe `df.orderBy('batch_date.desc).first()` ?

Comment: This solution won't be more efficient than the one shown. A `orderBy` will have to order all the elements, requiring a shuffle of all rows in the dataframe. In the `groupBy` solution will find the max value of each data partition, and only shuffle these elements, then find the maximum of all the maximums.
You won't find any more efficient than the group by, if you need to do it faster maybe do it with the HDFS API to prevent a spark job.

Answer (score 3):

Doing the method suggested by @pasha701 would involve loading the entire spark data frame with all the batch_date partitions and then finding max of that. I think the author is asking for a way to directly find the max partition date and load only that.
One way is to use hdfs or s3fs, and load the contents of the s3 path as a list and then finding the max partition and then loading only that. That would be more efficient.

Assuming you are using AWS s3 format, something like this:

```
import sys
import s3fs

datelist=[]
inpath="s3:bucket_path/data/"
fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=False)
Dirs = fs.ls(inpath)
for paths in Dirs:
    date=paths.split('=')[1]
    datelist.append(date)
maxpart=max(datelist)

df=spark.read.parquet("s3://bucket_path/data/batch_date=" + maxpart)
```

This would do all the work in lists without loading anything into memory until it finds the one you want to load.

Answer (score 1):

Function "max" can be used without "groupBy":

```
df.select(max("batch_date"))
```

Comment: This will do exactly the same as the solution of the author.

Answer (score 1):

The parquet files should contain the max values of columns in their metadata, so ideally Spark would exploit this to speed up queries.

This appears to be supported in Spark 3.3+, but currently disabled by default.
You would need to enable `spark.sql.parquet.aggregatePushdown`.

From the [spark parquet documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html):

> If true, aggregates will be pushed down to Parquet for optimization. Support MIN, MAX and COUNT as aggregate expression. For MIN/MAX, support boolean, integer, float and date type. For COUNT, support all data types. If statistics is missing from any Parquet file footer, exception would be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Using Show partitions to get all partition of table

```
show partitions TABLENAME
```

Output will be like

```
pt=2012.07.28.08/is_complete=1
pt=2012.07.28.09/is_complete=1
```

we can get data form specific partition using below query

```
select * from TABLENAME where pt='2012.07.28.10' and is_complete='1' limit 1;
```

Or additional filter or group by can be applied on it.

Comment: The `show partitions TABLENAME` doesn't work in pyspark

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in Pyspark v2.4.3. First extract partitions (*this is for a dataframe with a single partition on a date column, haven't tried it when a table has >1 partitions*):

```
df_partitions = spark.sql("show partitions database.dataframe")
```

"show partitions" returns dataframe with single column called 'partition' with values like partitioned_col=2022-10-31. Now we create a 'value' column extracting just the date part as string. This is then converted to date and the max is taken:

```
date_filter = df_partitions.withColumn('value', to_date(split('partition', '=')[1], 'yyyy-MM-dd')).agg({"value":"max"}).first()[0]
```

date_filter contains the maximum date from the partition and can be used in a where clause pulling from the same table.